# Java: validating a certain string pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate a string in a 'iterative way' and all my tryouts just fail!
I find it a bit complicated and i'm guessing maybe you could teach me how to do it right.
I assume that most of you will suggest me to use regex patterns but i dont really know how, and in general, how can a regex be defined for infinite "sets"?

The string i want to validate is 
"ANYTHING|NUMBER_ONLY,ANYTHING|NUMBER_ONLY..."

for example: "hello|5,word|10" and "hello|5,word|10," are both valid.

note: I dont mind if the string ends with or without a comma ','.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kleene star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) (`*`) lets you define "infinite sets" in regular expressions. Following pattern should do the trick:

```
[^,|]+\|\d+(,[^,|]+\|\d+)*,?
A----------B--------------C-
```

Part A matches the first element. Part B matches any following elements (notice the star). Part C is the optional comma at the end.

WARNING: Remember to escape backslashes in Java string.

Comment: Wow, almost perfect. it seems that a string like: "aa|3,aa|4,hi|aa,  aa|6" have passed the test :<

Comment: Oh, I see. Please check the new version. `[^,|]` matches anything except `,` and `|`.

Comment: And amazingly, it works! that's quite unbelievable, if ure about to open a regex course, im in! Thanks again!

Comment: Im really interested to know if i also understand it: correct me if im wrnog but the first part "[^,|]+\|" says match anything with | at the end (when u excluded ',' and '|' at the beginning) and when using + u expect it to be only this | to end the first part, and the second part "\d+(,[^,|]+\|\d+)*,?" means: "\d" any number + (same sequence from beginning)* when the * notation is the kleene star which lets us define "infinite sets" like u said, and as for the ",?" it means it can end either with or without a ',', have i understand it right?

Comment: Congrats! You missed only `+`, or the Kleene plus. `A+` means "one or more As". Similarly, `[^,|]+` means "one or more non-comma non-pipe characters" and `\d+` means "one or more digits". The Kleene star is the "zero or more" version of the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest splitting your string to array by `|` delimiter. And validate each part separately. Each part (except first one) should match following pattern `\d+(,.*)?`

**UPDATED**

Split by `,` and validate each part with `.*|\d+`

Comment: That doesn't quite make sense given the test input. Comma is the higher-level separator and | is the inner separator.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik hm, really. Thanks, I didn't notice it.

Comment: Marko is right.. how do u separate between numbers to any other words?

Comment: Thank you I am trying at the moment